Can I use FloatingActionButton and NavigationSuiteScaffold together?
I am using NavigationSuiteScaffold for navigation in my app. I want to add a FloatingActionButton to my app while still having adaptive navigation for small and large screens, but I can't figure out how to add elements that would usually be in a Scaffold to my app.

NavigationSuiteScaffold has no parameters for floating action buttons (and bars)

Adding a Scaffold inside of a NavigationSuiteScaffold doesn't display properly on large screens
Example Image


Is there a way to display an FAB according to the Material Design Guidelines while using adaptive navigation?

Can you describe what the issue is with the screenshot?

@tyg the FAB on the tablet size doesn't follow the material design guidelines specifically on the Responsive Layout section

This is not possible currently out of the box. There is a Feature Request open on the Google Issue Tracker, the design team is investigating it. You can leave a comment there and upvote the issue to draw more attention to it.
You can implement this yourself as follows (Screenshots below):
NavigationSuiteScaffoldFab.kt
@Composable
fun NavigationSuiteScaffoldFab(
    navigationSuiteItems: NavigationSuiteScope.() -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    layoutType: NavigationSuiteType =
        NavigationSuiteScaffoldDefaults.calculateFromAdaptiveInfo(currentWindowAdaptiveInfo()),
    navigationSuiteColors: NavigationSuiteColors = NavigationSuiteDefaults.colors(),
    containerColor: Color = NavigationSuiteScaffoldDefaults.containerColor,
    contentColor: Color = NavigationSuiteScaffoldDefaults.contentColor,
    floatingActionButton: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier, color = containerColor, contentColor = contentColor) {
        NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout(
            navigationSuite = {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    if (layoutType == NavigationSuiteType.NavigationRail 
                        || layoutType == NavigationSuiteType.NavigationDrawer) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        ) {
                            floatingActionButton()
                        }
                    }
                    NavigationSuite(
                        layoutType = layoutType,
                        colors = navigationSuiteColors,
                        content = navigationSuiteItems
                    )
                }
            },
            layoutType = layoutType,
            content = {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.consumeWindowInsets(
                        when (layoutType) {
                            NavigationSuiteType.NavigationBar ->
                                NavigationBarDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Bottom)
                            NavigationSuiteType.NavigationRail ->
                                NavigationRailDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Start)
                            NavigationSuiteType.NavigationDrawer ->
                                DrawerDefaults.windowInsets.only(WindowInsetsSides.Start)
                            else -> WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }
                    ),
                    floatingActionButton = {
                        if (layoutType == NavigationSuiteType.NavigationBar) {
                            floatingActionButton()
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                        content()
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

Usage
@Composable
fun NavigationSuiteDemo() {

    var currentDestination by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(AppDestinations.HOME) }

    NavigationSuiteScaffoldFab(
        navigationSuiteItems = {
            AppDestinations.entries.forEach {
                item(
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            it.icon,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(it.contentDescription)
                        )
                    },
                    label = { Text(stringResource(it.label)) },
                    selected = it == currentDestination,
                    onClick = { currentDestination = it }
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {}
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Edit, "")
            }
        }
    ) {
        // TODO: Destination content.
    }
}

enum class AppDestinations(
    @StringRes val label: Int,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    @StringRes val contentDescription: Int
) {
    HOME(R.string.home, Icons.Default.Home, R.string.home),
    FAVORITES(R.string.favorites, Icons.Default.Favorite, R.string.favorites),
    SHOPPING(R.string.shopping, Icons.Default.ShoppingCart, R.string.shopping),
    PROFILE(R.string.profile, Icons.Default.AccountBox, R.string.profile),
}

Output:


